# explode function does not work on a string in PHP

Tags: php, explode

The `echo $line_of_text;` gives me `"test1 test2 test1 test2 "`
But once I use the `explode` by `' '` it only divides the string by 2 parts. 
as a result it says `pieces[0] = test1test1` and `pieces[1]=test2test2`. I need it to be divided into 4. Thanks in regards.

UPDATE: I found the problem. The function seemed to be in a `foreach` loop. It ran twice. I found out about it when I ran echo `$pieces[0].'<br>';`. It gave me: 

Test1 test2 
Test1 test2

After some fixing I got it to work as I intended. Thanks for the quick responses.

```
    public function load_time_period()
{
    $file_handle = fopen($GLOBALS['configfile_time_periods'], "r+");

    $i = -1;
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {

        $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);

        switch ($line_of_text) {

            case stripos($line_of_text, "define timeperiod") > -1:
                if (stripos($line_of_text, "define timeperiod") > -1) {
                    $i++;
                    $obj_time_periods[$i] = new nagmon_time_period();
                }
                break;

            case stripos($line_of_text, "timeperiod_name") > -1:
                $obj_time_periods[$i]->set_timeperiod_name(trim(str_replace("#", "", str_replace("timeperiod_name", "", $line_of_text))));
                break;

            case stripos($line_of_text, "alias") > -1:
                $obj_time_periods[$i]->set_alias(trim(str_replace("#", "", str_replace("alias", "", $line_of_text))));
                break;

            case stripos($line_of_text, "weekday") > -1:
                $obj_time_periods[$i]->set_weekday(trim(str_replace("#", "", str_replace("[weekday]", "", $line_of_text))));
                break;

            case stripos($line_of_text, "exception") > -1:
                $obj_time_periods[$i]->set_exception(trim(str_replace("#", "", str_replace("[exception]", "", $line_of_text))));
                break;
            case stripos($line_of_text, "exclude") > -1:
                $obj_time_periods[$i]->set_exclude(trim(str_replace("#", "", str_replace("exclude", "", $line_of_text))));
                break;

            case stripos($line_of_text, " ") > -1:



                echo htmlentities($line_of_text);



                $obj_time_periods[$i]->set_variable_command($pieces[0]);
                $obj_time_periods[$i]->set_variable_value($pieces[1]);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $obj_time_periods;


}
```

Comment: Maybe they're not all really space characters.

Comment: Probably a `echo htmlentities($line_of_text);` helps to see more.

Comment: post the contents of `$line_of_text`

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries i inspected it with firebug. Directly copied it says the following:test1 test2  test1 test2 . I noticed that it has 2 spaces between the middle test2 and test 1.

Comment: @Snekmel Do a plain echo of  `$line_of_text;` just before you use it and see what it prints out. mybe after the `echo htmlentities($line_of_text);` line. Copy it directly, not from firebug

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries Thanks for the response. Once i copy it from the echo $line_of_text; It gives me : test1 test2 test1 test2.

Comment: @Snekmel : if it still brings up the error, then it means that in reality, `pieces[0] = test1test1` there is no spaces between the two test1 strings, as a matter of fact, your final output value for `$line_of_text;` might be `test1test1 test2test2` Go through your code and debug

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries Thanks! i debugged it and i got it to work now.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to explode by any space or tab or by more spaces or tabs:

```
$pieces = preg_split('/\s+/u', trim($line_of_text));
print_r($pieces);
//Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => test1 [3] => test2 )
```

Comment: It gives me the same result. pieces[0] = test1test1 and pieces[1]=test2test2

Comment: then there was no space between test1 and test1 as well as test2 and test2

Comment: Thanks for the response again. Do you have any idea what it might could be? since when i print the full variable it gives me: test1 test2 test1 test2. I noticed that there are 2 spaces between the middle test2 and test1. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Take another look at the `$line_of_text` var before splitting it, it isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries once i try gettype($line_of_text); it says to be a string.

Comment: maybe try with `/u` modifier for utf8 characters - like in updated regex pattern.

Comment: @Snekmel, it might be a string yes, but not what you expect, something like `test1test1 test2test2`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the error is happening before. Can you share more of your code? When I try this

```
$line_of_text = "test1 test2 test1 test2 ";

$pieces = explode(' ', $line_of_text);
var_dump($pieces);
```

It gives me the output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "test1"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "test2"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "test1"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "test2"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

which is correct.

You can try out small snippets like this in an online interpreter, for example here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code. This is my full function. It reads configurations out of a text file.